# Setting an unsupported custom resolution in MacOS

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, hdmi, resolution

Is there a way via command line or GUI to set a custom unsupported screen resolution. Specifically the problem I am trying to resolve is getting 5K support for a Dell U4919DW.

If not possible, how do I set my Macbook to run 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI? The option is not available in the display menu.

Currently running the latest version of MacOS Mojave (10.14.6) on MacBook Pro Early 2015.

Comment: There's a difference between 'custom unsupported' & 'bigger than the machine is capable of'. That Mac can't do 5k.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, this mac will support 5K. [Proof](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587)

Comment: I'm afraid your 'proof' quite clearly says otherwise. 2016/7 models & up generally support 5k. Yours can do 3840x2160 via TB2 or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI. Source: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-3.1-13-early-2015-retina-display-specs.html

Comment: @Tetsujin ok, in that case - How do i set my Macbook to run 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI? The option is not available in the display menu.

Comment: That's probably because the screen can't do that resolution. [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com) can do custom resolutions, but both the Mac & the monitor have to be able to support it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Awesome, I saw that SwitchResX was able to do it. I wanted kind of a lower level knowledge on how it is actually done. How does SwitchResX work?

Comment: Sorry, I've no clue how it actually does it.